# Jcrop default selection box

Tags: jquery, jcrop

```
$('#previewImg').Jcrop({
        onChange: showCoords,  
        onSelect: showCoords,
        minSize:[300,100],
        maxSize:[900,900],
        aspectRatio: 3/1
    });
```

I have an image use jcrop, however i need to have a default box 300,100 before user click on image to make it appear.

so the box will already appear & at center before user click the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to set the `setSelect` option while creating the jcrop

```
$('#previewImg').Jcrop({
        onChange: showCoords,  
        onSelect: showCoords,
        setSelect: [0, 160, 160, 0],// you have set proper x and y coordinates here
        minSize:[300,100],
        maxSize:[900,900],
        aspectRatio: 3/1
    });
```

Here is the demo for setSelect option http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced